Pycharm keep showing error on reading Selenium Library
So I'm struggling with this error for few weeks already.
I have this error:
Features.1 Login                                                              
==============================================================================
Login Valid                                                           | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Open Browser' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Features.1 Login                                                      | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Features                                                              | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
[FAIL (+0.03s)] No keyword with name 'Open Browser' found.
Output:  /Users/ii/PycharmProjects/DV2Robot_Framework/log/output.xml
Log:     /Users/ii/PycharmProjects/DV2Robot_Framework/log/log.html
Report:  /Users/ii/PycharmProjects/DV2Robot_Framework/log/report.html

This test cases are run successfully on my Windows.
This is the error that I got :
[ERROR] Error in file '/Users/ii/PycharmProjects/DV2Robot_Framework/Vault2_Testing/import_resources.robot' on line 2: Importing library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SeleniumLibrary'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  /Users/ii/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2024.1/plugins/robotframework-intellij/lib/robotframework_debug_adapter
  /Users/ii/PycharmProjects/DV2Robot_Framework
  /Users/ii/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2024.1/plugins/robotframework-intellij/lib
  /Users/ii/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2024.1/plugins/robotframework-intellij/lib/robotframework_ls/vendored
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
  /Users/ii/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages

I've already run many times the 'source activate' command, but the error still remain.
And several times of pip install seleniumlibrary also.
My interpreter is located at /Users/ii/PycharmProjects/DV2Robot_Framework/.venv/bin/python.
Below is my current files structure :

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

maybe use python to check modules /Users/ii/PycharmProjects/DV2Robot_Framework/.venv/bin/python -m pip ...

The actual library is not called seleniumlibrary but robotframework-seleniumlibrary.  Probably worse to check
